# how to make a (ggplot) line plot with different color segments conditional on direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

As per Shanes excellent [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544907/melt-to-two-variable-columns) of another question, I now realise that I do not know how to do this.

My original approach was to use melt the data (thanks again shane):

```
dm1 <- melt(d[,c("Type","I.alt","idx06","idx07","idx08")], id=c("Type","I.alt"))
dm2 <- melt(d[,c("Type","I.alt","farve1","farve2")], id=c("Type","I.alt"))
colnames(dm2) <- c("Type", "I.alt", "variable2", "value2")
dm <- merge(dm1, dm2)
```

And then make the plot:

```
ggplot(dm, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=Type,label=Type,size=I.alt))+
  geom_line(aes(col=value2))+
  geom_text(data=subset(dm, variable=="idx08"),hjust=-0.2, size=2.5)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,1))+
  opts(legend.position="none")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","red"))
```

But it's not working (all the individual line pieces going "up" should be red, all going "down" should be green):

[BTW:does the png device insist on geom_point? http://wana.dk/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/damn.png](http://wana.dk/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/damn.png)

(bonus question 1: how can I use expand to only expand to the right? (where my labels ' at.))

(bonus question 2: Both png and pdf device shows up like above - i.e. with geom_points - this does not happen on my screen)

This is my data:

```
d <- structure(list(Type = structure(c(8L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 6L, 14L, 
3L, 24L, 2L, 28L, 32L, 22L, 15L, 29L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 33L, 25L, 
13L, 30L, 11L, 26L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 27L, 16L, 19L, 10L, 31L, 
7L), .Label = c("Alvorligere vold", "Andre strafferetlige særlove", 
"Andre tyverier", "Bedrageri", "Brandstiftelse", "Butikstyverier m.v.", 
"Dokumentfalsk", "Færdselslovovertræd. i øvrigt", "Færdselsuheld med spiritus", 
"Falsk forklaring i øvrigt", "Forbr. mod off. myndighed m.v.", 
"Freds- og ærekrænkelser", "Hæleri", "Hærværk", "Indbrud i bank, forretn. m.v.", 
"Indbrud i fritidshuse, garager mv", "Indbrud i villaer, lejligheder mv", 
"Love vedr. forsvaret og lign.", "Love vedr. spil, bev., næring", 
"Lov om euforiserende stoffer", "Mangler ved køretøj", "Røveri", 
"Simpel vold", "Spiritus- og promillekørsel", "Trusler", "Tyv./brugstyv. af andet", 
"Tyv./brugstyv. af cykel", "Tyv./brugstyv. af indr. køretøj", 
"Tyv/brugstyv. af knallert", "Tyveri fra bil, båd m.v.", "Ulovlig omgang med hittegods", 
"Våbenloven", "Vold o.l. mod off. myndighed"), class = "factor"), 
I.alt = c(16137L, 9519L, 5930L, 5502L, 4887L, 3582L, 3101L, 
1738L, 1660L, 1649L, 1551L, 1412L, 1338L, 1164L, 1154L, 1057L, 
931L, 907L, 857L, 724L, 681L, 644L, 641L, 505L, 450L, 419L, 
405L, 328L, 324L, 324L, 320L, 281L, 262L), idx06 = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), idx07 = c(0.972675591417568, 
0.766866371450899, 0.931743805516597, 0.813047711781889, 
0.88728323699422, 0.96420233463035, 0.855743544078362, 1.03710247349823, 
0.751470588235294, 0.90443686006826, 0.808403361344538, 0.902834008097166, 
0.718181818181818, 0.904555314533623, 1.02717391304348, 0.68957345971564, 
1.10324483775811, 0.93030303030303, 0.805309734513274, 0.843003412969283, 
0.74914089347079, 0.824786324786325, 1.04060913705584, 1.09150326797386, 
0.977941176470588, 0.892405063291139, 0.966666666666667, 
0.828125, 0.696, 0.813559322033898, 0.697841726618705, 0.88235294117647, 
0.62280701754386), idx08 = c(0.986612873647533, 0.712685595207085, 
0.840579710144927, 0.865628042843233, 0.93757225433526, 0.823346303501945, 
0.905609973285841, 1.03356890459364, 0.689705882352941, 0.909556313993174, 
0.798319327731092, 0.955465587044534, 0.714545454545455, 
0.620390455531453, 1.10869565217391, 0.815165876777251, 0.64306784660767, 
0.818181818181818, 0.722713864306785, 0.627986348122867, 
0.59106529209622, 0.927350427350427, 1.21319796954315, 1.20915032679739, 
1.33088235294118, 0.759493670886076, 1.40833333333333, 0.734375, 
0.896, 0.932203389830508, 0.60431654676259, 0.872549019607843, 
0.675438596491228), farve1 = c("green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "red", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "red", "green", "red", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "red", "red", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green"), farve2 = c("red", "green", "green", "red", 
"red", "green", "red", "green", "green", "red", "green", 
"red", "green", "green", "red", "red", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "red", "red", "red", "red", "green", 
"red", "green", "red", "red", "green", "green", "red")), .Names = c("Type", 
"I.alt", "idx06", "idx07", "idx08", "farve1", "farve2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

Comment: link to the picture is broken (12/10/12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your merge didn't work because you only had two colour variables, but three data values. Adding a third colour variable as padding seems to do the trick. geom_line takes it's colour from the previous datapoint's value, so the last value of "value2" is not used.

```
d$farve3<-NA
dm1 <- melt(d[,c("Type","I.alt","idx06","idx07","idx08")], id=c("Type","I.alt"))
dm2 <- melt(d[,c("Type","I.alt","farve1","farve2","farve3")], id=c("Type","I.alt"))
colnames(dm2) <- c("Type", "I.alt", "variable2", "value2")
dm<-cbind(dm1,dm2)
ggplot(dm, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=Type,label=Type,size=I.alt))+
  geom_line(aes(col=value2))+
  geom_text(data=subset(dm, variable=="idx08"),hjust=-0.2, size=2.5)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,1))+
  opts(legend.position="none")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","red"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just [point out this related question.](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/5fa2756f15124b25)  It's a real leap to go from this solution to solving your particular problem, but I'm posting this in case it might help.

With this sample data:

```
b<-cumsum(rnorm(100))
x<-sample(c(1,2), size=100, replace=TRUE)
t<-1:(length(b))
```

Here x would represent your values, b is the color (rising/falling), and t is the x-axis.  Reformat it with melt:

```
library(ggplot2)
tmp <- melt(data.frame(cbind(t,b,x)),meas=c("x"))
head(tmp)
```

And plot it:

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=t,groups=variable)) +
        facet_wrap(~variable) +
        geom_path(aes(y=b,colour=factor(value))) +
        labs(x=NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks again Shane. It seams that geom_path requires a sorting of the data that would be difficult in my case.

Comment: In 2020, (gggplot 3.2.1) I had to change groups to singular *group* to get it to run in `ggplot(tmp, aes(x=t,group=variable))`